# How do I make an image histogram?

Tags: c#

I have to make an image histogram in the red, green and blue planes.

I have this code, but it is in Visual Basic and I need it in C#
I need to open an image, and to that image I have to make its histogram.

```
Public Class Form1

Public Function histogramaAcumulado(ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Integer(,)
    'Creamos una matriz que contendrá el histograma acumulado
    Dim Rojo, Verde, Azul As Byte 'Declaramos tres variables que almacenarán los colores
    Dim matrizAcumulada(2, 255) As Integer
    For i = 0 To bmp.Width - 1 'Recorremos la matriz
        For j = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
            Rojo = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).R 'Asignamos el color
            Verde = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).G
            Azul = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).B
            'ACumulamos los valores. 
            matrizAcumulada(0, Rojo) += 1
            matrizAcumulada(1, Verde) += 1
            matrizAcumulada(2, Azul) += 1
        Next
    Next
    Return matrizAcumulada
End Function

Dim histoAcumulado As Integer(,) 'Variable que almacenará los histogramas
Private Sub Form1_(Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Cargamos los histogramas
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
    histoAcumulado = histogramaAcumulado(bmp)
    'Ejecutamos el botón del histograma rojo
    Button1_Click(sender, e)
End Sub

'Histograma rojo
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Borramos el posible contenido del chart
    Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.Clear()
    'Los ponesmos del colores correspondiente
    Chart1.Series("Histograma").Color = Color.Red
    For i = 0 To 255
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.AddXY(i + 1, histoAcumulado(0, i))
    Next
End Sub
'Histograma verde
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Borramos el posible contenido del chart
    Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.Clear()
    Chart1.Series("Histograma").Color = Color.Green
    For i = 0 To 255
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.AddXY(i + 1, histoAcumulado(1, i))
    Next
End Sub
'Histograma azul
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Borramos el posible contenido del chart
    Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.Clear()
    Chart1.Series("Histograma").Color = Color.Blue
    For i = 0 To 255
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.AddXY(i + 1, histoAcumulado(2, i))
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Do you have a question other than "write my code for me?" What _specific_ problem are you seeking help with? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates that specific problem, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0):

> and I need it in C# I need to open an image, and to that image I have to make its histogram

If I understood your question it is essentially that of converting VB.NET to c#.  The original code was already creating the histogram and can be seen below in `histogramaAcumulado()`.

---

**Note**: Generally on SO we prefer that source code be in *English*.  I have not performed any language translation.

**Additional Note**: The original code also makes come references to an undefined `Chart1` member thus flagging the code below as **uncompilable** as well as the *original code*.  I leave it as an exercise for the OP to further explorer the original VB code to decipher its meaning.

---

Please find the c# code below:

```
public class Form1
{
    public int[,] histogramaAcumulado(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        //Creamos una matriz que contendrá el histograma acumulado
        byte Rojo = 0;
        byte Verde = 0;
        byte Azul = 0;
        //Declaramos tres variables que almacenarán los colores
        int[,] matrizAcumulada = new int[3, 256];
        //Recorremos la matriz
        for (i = 0; i <= bmp.Width - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= bmp.Height - 1; j++)
            {
                Rojo = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).R;
                //Asignamos el color
                Verde = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).G;
                Azul = bmp.GetPixel(i, j).B;
                //ACumulamos los valores. 
                matrizAcumulada[0, Rojo] += 1;
                matrizAcumulada[1, Verde] += 1;
                matrizAcumulada[2, Azul] += 1;
            }
        }
        return matrizAcumulada;
    }

    //Variable que almacenará los histogramas
    int[,] histoAcumulado;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cargamos los histogramas
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image);
        histoAcumulado = histogramaAcumulado(bmp);
        //Ejecutamos el botón del histograma rojo
        Button1_Click(sender, e);
    }

    //Histograma rojo
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Borramos el posible contenido del chart
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.Clear();
        //Los ponesmos del colores correspondiente
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Color = Color.Red;
        for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.AddXY(i + 1, histoAcumulado[0, i]);
        }
    }
    //Histograma verde
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Borramos el posible contenido del chart
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.Clear();
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Color = Color.Green;
        for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.AddXY(i + 1, histoAcumulado[1, i]);
        }
    }
    //Histograma azul
    private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Borramos el posible contenido del chart
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.Clear();
        Chart1.Series("Histograma").Color = Color.Blue;
        for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            Chart1.Series("Histograma").Points.AddXY(i + 1, histoAcumulado[2, i]);
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }

}
```

### Conversion Tools

For your interest the code was converted via [SharpDevelop Snippet Converter](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx).